# onclick function not working on an icon which is on a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a modal. There is a icon on which i want to perform an operation.
Below is my function which I am calling on click event of an icon but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.fc-day', function() {
            $('#tmd_schedule').modal('toggle');
        });
        $(document).on('click', '#add_tmd', function() {
            console.log("hi");
        });
});
```

Here is my html code

```
<i class="fa fa-plus col-md-2 form-control-feedback" id="add_tmd"></i>
```

Comment: could you post the html aswell?

Comment: @Poku here it is

Comment: Where is `.fc-day` ??

Comment: is the <i> tag dynamically created? if not, you don't need the` $(document)` prefix for the `.on()`

Comment: try using class selector ?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs no.. they are not created dynamically..

Comment: @varVijayShah then why use `$(document)`? use `$('#id')` instead - `$(document)` is mainly used for dynamic html

Comment: @IsmailFarooq that too tried

Comment: Though its not created dynamically, but this is better to delegate an event.

Comment: @varVijayShah Better you create the working example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your html to..

```
<i id="add_tmd" class="fa fa-plus pull-right"></i>
```

Just Remove the `form-control-feedback` class from your icon. It has [`pointer-events: none;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35991662/2724173) property in [bootstrap css](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation). That's why you are not able to click on icon.

Comment: Worked perfectly

Comment: Could you give an explanation, please?

Comment: i also dont know how it worked..?

Comment: According to me class="form-control-feedback" was causing some problem

Comment: the problem is form-control-feedback has pointer-events: none; in bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#add_tmd').click(function() { console.log("hi"); });` instead.

Using a document selector doesn't really make sense here; using an element selector would be more valid. In addition, the `click()` function performs the same thing as `on('click', ...)`, but it's more succinct.

Comment: Explain your code - don't just write code

Answer (score 0):

Look on below code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.fa-calendar', function() {
            //$('#tmd_schedule').modal('toggle');
             console.log("hi");
        });
        $(document).on('click', '#add_tmd', function() {
           console.log("hello");
        });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-plus col-md-2 form-control-feedback" id="add_tmd">
</i>
<i class="fa fa-calendar col-md-2 form-control-feedback"></i>
```

click is added on icon, might be issue is with your modal.

Comment: Please explain your code.

Comment: Duplicate ids for `id="add_tmd"`.

Comment: thanx. updated ,my code.

Answer (score 0):

Where you are attaching your click event does  not look right,

```
 $(document).on('click', '.fa-calendar', function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check documentation for the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function. Because previous versions of jQuery with live and delegate functions having same behaviour.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        
        $(document.body).on('click', '#add_tmd', function() {
            alert("hi");
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-plus col-md-2 form-control-feedback" id="add_tmd">Test</i>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the selector instead of the document to add click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fc-day').on('click', function() {
            $('#tmd_schedule').modal('toggle');
        });
        $('#add_tmd').on('click', function() {
            console.log("hi");
        });
});
```

You could also use the jquery click function to simplify it a bit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fc-day').click(function() {
            $('#tmd_schedule').modal('toggle');
        });
        $('#add_tmd').click(function() {
            console.log("hi");
        });
});
```

Comment: it might be dynamically created, which is why it's using document